# Approximating Large Nonlinear Integer Optimization

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

Let $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a positiv semi-definite matrix, let $K \in \mathbb{N}$ and let  $u \in \mathbb{R^{n}}$.
I need to solve the integer programming problem:

$$\max_{x \in \mathbb{N}^n} x^Tu - x^TQx \\ \text{s.t.} \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \le K $$

Here $n$ is very large, too large to allow for any of the standard algorithms to converge in reasonable time.

An approximate solution would already be good enough, but I am unsure how to get it - unfortunately, discrete optimization is really not my field of expertise.

I was thinking about some kind of dimensionality reduction of $Q$ (maybe SVD?) since $Q$ has mostly entries that are close to zero. Another idea I had was to repeatedly fix random entries of $x$ to be zero and optimize over the remaining ones to see which ones are reasonable for a gobal optimum (after all, only at most $K$ can be different from $0$ due to the linear constraint).

Finally, permutation-based "Pseudo-Gradient-Descent" comes to mind (we can easily check how the objective function behaves under small changes of $x$).

Is there a better way to tackle this? Of course, it is clear to me that we have no guarantee to truly find the maximum unless we do standard mixed integer quadratic programming.

Are there more sophisticated approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following greedy heuristic with at most $K$ steps.  Initialize $x_i=0$ for all $i$.  In each step, loop over $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ to find the $i$ whose incremental improvement to the objective value is largest, and update this $x_i$ to $x_i+1$ if the improvement is positive.  This yields a feasible solution.

From any feasible starting solution, you can optionally perform a local search on (random?) pairs $(x_i,x_j)$ to see if perturbing to $(x_i+1,x_j-1)$ or $(x_i-1,x_j+1)$ improves the solution.